# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting

Tags: android, flutter

Step I have taken

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- invalidate cache
- delete build file
  and this error still persist.

Anyone has a better approach to solve this

[image]

Comment: This may help you : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72730

Comment: ok thanks, let me have a look